# Can a long polymer chain interact with itself via van der Waals forces?

Tags: polymers, intermolecular-forces

It is known that van der Waals interaction is an intermolecular forces. So is it possible that a long polymer chain interacting with itself via non-bonded interactions (such as van der Waals forces / electrostatic forces / hydrogen bonding)?

Comment: It can and does. Come to think of it, how can it _not_ to interact? It is just the same atoms governed by the same laws. They don't have a built-in [IFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identification_friend_or_foe) system to tell them whether the other atom is from the same or different molecule.

Comment: Why these are called intermolecular interactions, they're *intra*molecular as well, it's just that they're secondary to covalent bonds.

Answer (score 13):

You have a possible answer to your question in proteins, an example which includes some long polymer chains.

Intramolecular interactions - while not necessarily the driving force for formation of a collapsed protein globule (usually argued to be due to the hydrophobic effect, requiring *inter*molecular interactions) - are the basis for higher order structure in proteins and even some forms of RNA. I won't mention DNA since most commonly this forms a bimolecular double helix.

All of the interactions you mention may play a role in stabilizing a particular protein structure or "fold". A good and basic example of protein structure acquisition due to *intra*molecular interactions in proteins is polyalanine, which acquires alpha-helical secondary structure stabilized by intramolecular hydrogen bonds, typically between amide groups separated by 2 amino acids along the chain. Other types of structure stabilized by intramolecular interactions (H-bonds, usually) in polypeptides include other types of helices, beta sheets and various turns.